# How can I see if a user uses my product two months in a row ? (SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, comparison, retention

I would like to know if a user who logged in to my product one month, logged in the next month as well.

In the `WITH` part of my code you can find the list of all the ids of the people who have logged in at least once in the month, and the associated month.

I would like to make a second part where I would have as a column the month, the number of people who connected this month, and the number of the same people who connected the next month.

I'm too sorry if my code is a mess, I'm a beginner and I did my best to make it clear!

Here's where I am stucked right now :

```
WITH monthly_active_users AS ( 
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(YYYYMM, '-01')) month, users FROM(
select ym.YYYYMM,
ARRAY(select t.recipient
        from (SELECT recipient, 
            DATE(date) AS messagedate, 
            FROM messages) t
       WHERE FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m",t.messagedate) = ym.YYYYMM) as userid

FROM (select distinct FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", date) as YYYYMM,
      from messages
     ) ym
WHERE ym.YYYYMM <= FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m",CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY ym.YYYYMM DESC)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(userid) AS users
)


SELECT t.month, COUNT(t.users) mon_count,
-- (
     -- SELECT COUNT(users)
     -- FROM (SELECT t1.users 
     -- FROM monthly_active_users t1
     -- JOIN monthly_active_users t2 
     -- on t1.month=DATE_SUB(t2.month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
     -- GROUP BY t1.month
     -- ) t1 WHERE DATE(CONCAT(t1.YYYYMM, '-01')) = DATE_SUB(t.YYYYMM, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
-- )
FROM monthly_active_users t
GROUP BY month
ORDER by month DESC
```

The last part in `--` was a test, don't mind it haha

Thanks for the help and have an awesome day !

Comment: Two nested selects in an array. Please start with `With tbl as (Select date_trunc(date_column,month) as YYYYMM, userid, count(1) as login_per_month from your_datset.your_table group by 1,2)` Then you will need a windows function: `Select *, date_diff(YYYYMM,lag(YYYYMM) over win_1,month)=1  from tbl window win_1 as (partition by userid order by YYYYMM) `

Comment: Yaaaaaaay ! Thanks a lot I succeed with your help ! ❤️